# С помощью каких программ можно визуально создавать GUI, а потом подключать его к проектам vc++?

Tags: windows, gui, visual-c++

Слышал что-то про `Qt`

Comment: Например, при помощи встроенного в Visual Studio [редактора диалогов MFC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2711197/276994). Но лучше переходите на связку C#/WPF.

Comment: C#/WPF? это была шутка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чём вопрос? С помощью каких программ или библиотек? Да, можно использовать Qt - это фреймворк (грубым языком можно назвать это библиотеками). С ним советую использовать QtCreator.

Qt имеет модули как для работы с GUI (QtGui), так и для работы с сетью, базами данный и кучу других.

Можно использовать средства Visual Studio, но я, как их ненавистник, промолчу по этому поводу.